# Filter options by reading character length inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, for-loop

I have a widget (the widget code in the pen linked below is not the actual code, please just pay attention to the filtering function `jQuery.fn.doFilterOptions(){..}`).

**Use case:**

I have a non-native selectbox. I need to extend its functionality to accept an `onclick` event which allows the user to type data into the selectbox (not targeting a traditional `<select>`), it should filter the `.options` available by simply showing or hiding them based on its inner HTML value, if no match is found at any point during the loop through the string being entered by the user, I need the options to continue not being displayed.

**Issue:**

Right now it works 95% of the way, the only issue is that if an invalid char is found, the loop keeps checking the rest of the users entries char by char, and if the next char is a match to any of the options in the same index, it re-display's this as a valid .option.

```
$('.selectbox .selected').on('keyup', function(){
  var theseOptions = $(this).parent('.selectbox').find('.option');
  var defaultPlaceholder = $(this).data('placeholder');

  var filterOptions = (function(curSelectedVal){
    if (curSelectedVal === ' ' || curSelectedVal.length === 0 || curSelectedVal === defaultPlaceholder){
      theseOptions.show();
    }
    var optionsVal; 
    var doInputOptionsComparison = (function(){
       var invalidOption = false;
      for (var letterPos = 0; letterPos < curSelectedVal.length; letterPos++){
        theseOptions.each(function(optionIteration){ 

          var thisOption = $(this);
          thisOptionsVal = thisOption.html();

          if (curSelectedVal.length > thisOptionsVal.length ){ // If a longer string has been input by the user than exists in the option being iterated over, hide this option
            thisOption.hide();
            invalidOption = true;
          }
          else if ((thisOptionsVal[letterPos].toLowerCase().trim() === curSelectedVal[letterPos].toLowerCase().trim()) && invalidOption === false){ // If the input string matches this option and no invalid options have been found in the letterPos prior to it, show this option 
            thisOption.show();
          }
          else { // If the string does not match any option
            invalidOptionFound = true;
            thisOption.hide();
          }

        });
      }
    })();
  })($(this).html());
});
```

Here is the demo, try selecting then typing abz you will see the filter working properly.

Now erase that input data, and now type azc. You will see the abc option comes available again because the c matches in that same index (user input[i] = optionsHtml[i] = show();), resulting the the above described undesirable effect.

http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/KwwMPG?editors=001

**BONUS:**

Would this be easier by using regEx to do the filtering?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use a dynamic regEx filter function it it cut the code down big time! Wow what a better solution.

```
$.fn.filterOptionsByUserInput = function(optionSelector){
        var curInput = $(this).html().trim().replace(/&nbsp;/g, '').toLowerCase();

        $(optionSelector).each(function(optionIndex){
            var userInputRegEx = new RegExp('^'+curInput+'.*');
            if ($(this).html().toLowerCase().trim().match(userInputRegEx)){
                $(this).fadeIn('slow');
            }
            else {
                $(this).fadeOut('slow');
            }
        });
    };
```

http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/LEEwrm?editors=001